# Почему так работает передача по ссылке в foreach

Tags: php

```
$array = array('image'=>'blabla.jpeg','status'=>1);
$unset = array('image');
foreach ($array as $k=>&$v) {

        //blabla

}

foreach ($unset as $k=>$v) {
        unset($array[$v]) ;
 }

print_r($array);
```

Есть вот такой код я не пойму почему в результате его выполнения получается

```
Array
    (
        [status] => image
    )
```

Comment: @ukroficer

    foreach ($unset as $k=>$v) {
        unset($array[$v]) ;
    }

1. берем каждый элемент $unset (там всего один, 'image')
2. удаляем из $array значение под ключом этого элемента (опять же 'image')

что не так?

Comment: почему status = image ?

Comment: @ukroficer Понял. Это очень забавная ситуация.  
Когда первый цикл заканчивается, $k и $v никуда не испаряются. Более того, $v продолжает *указывать* на последний элемент первого массива. Во время второго цикла $v присваивается значение первого элемента следующего массива. $v все еще указывает на элемент другого массива.

Comment: @unkoficer - что вместо bla bla?

Comment: я понимаю как это работает но почему? 

цикле то закончился и передача по ссылки только в первом цикле.

Comment: тем более в доке написано что при создание цикла переменные обнуляються

Comment: @ukroficer, я же выше написал

> тем более в доке написано что при создание цикла переменные обнуляються

не нашел там такого

Comment: сделайте $v= null;  перед вторым цыклом, все равно результат не  меняется.

Comment: чего не работает не пойму http://ideone.com/mOAjNH

Comment: а понял, делайте unset($v) чтобы освободить ссылку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очищайте $k и $v после цикла, по завершении цикла они продолжают хранить ссылки на последний элемент массива, и следующий цикл начнется не оттуда откуда вы думаете.

Эта ошибка хорошо описано в статье [10 Most Common PHP Mistakes](http://www.toptal.com/php/10-most-common-mistakes-php-programmers-make)